# Transactions should be handled in .NET or SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I got into an application which is using .NET/C# as front end and SQL Server 2008 as back end. I found that ALWAYS transactions are handled in the c# code. Seems its an unwritten rule for this project that we shouldn't use Transactions within stored procedure.

I personally feel that transactions should be handled within Stored Procedure as it would give more control over the code! We might have lot of validations happening within the script all this while we don't need a open transaction. We need to open a transaction just before we do a Insert/Update/Delete and can close it asap.

Looking for answers which would help me understand the best practice for handling transactions and when exactly do we need to opt for Transactions within Stored Proc / C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a hard and fast rule, but I see several reasons to control transactions from the business tier:

- Communication across data store boundaries. Transactions don't have to be against a RDBMS; they can be against a variety of entities.
- The ability to rollback/commit transactions based on business logic that may not be available to the particular stored procedure you are calling.
- The ability to invoke an arbitrary set of queries within a single transaction. This also eliminates the need to worry about transaction count.
- Personal preference: c# has a more elegant structure for declaring transactions: a `using` block. By comparison, I've always found transactions inside stored procedures to be cumbersome when jumping to rollback/commit.

> We might have lot of validations happening within the script all this
>   while we don't need a open transaction. We need to open a transaction
>   just before we do a Insert/Update/Delete and can close it asap.

This may or may not be a problem depending on how many transactions are being opened (it's not clear if this is a single job, or a procedure which is run with high concurrency). I would suggest looking at what locks are being placed on objects, and how long those locks are being held.

Keep in mind that validation possibly **should** lock; what if the data changes between the time you validated it and the time the action occurs?

If it **is** a problem, you could break the offending procedure into two procedures, and call one from outside of a `TransactionScope`.