# How do I minimize or inform users of database connection lag / failure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2005

I'm maintaining a ASP/C# program that uses an MS SQL Server 2008 R2 for its database requirements.

On normal and perfect days, everything works fine as it is. But we don't live in a perfect world.

An Application (for Leave, Sick Leave, Overtime, Undertime, etc.) Approval process requires up to ten separate connections to the database. The program connects to the database, passes around some relevant parameters, and uses stored procedures to do the job. Ten times.

Now, due to the structure of the entire thing, which I can not change, a dip in the connection, or heck, if I put a debug point in VS2005 and let it hang there long enough, the Application Approval Process goes incomplete. The tables are often just joined together, so a data mismatch - a missing data here, a primary key that failed to update there - would mean an entire row would be useless.

Now, I know that there is nothing I can do to prevent this - this is a connection issue, after all.

But are there ways to minimize connection lag / failure? Or a way to inform the users that something went wrong with the process? A rollback changes feature (either via program, or SQL), so that any incomplete data in the database will be undone?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the question again?

Comment: Profile/optimize (execution plans, traces, and tuning advisor are basic but can go a long way) to improve performance. It's not clear if you are using transactions, but if you aren't, they are a highly effective way of ensuring that the process doesn't fail and leave artifacts.

Comment: @O.O, sorry if it's not clear. Updated the question.

Comment: @TimMedora, the program simply connects to the database, passes some parameters, and executes the stored procedure. Probably doesn't use transactions - haven't heard of them until now, actually.

Comment: Definitely look at transactions, either using `System.Transactions.TransactionScope` or inside your stored procedures. Transactions are an "all or nothing" mechanism, i.e. they ensure that the whole operation succeeds or is rolled back. SQL Server does all the work for you.

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks. Looks promising. If you could enter your suggestion as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Sure, I'll write it up with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But are there ways to minimize connection lag / failure? Or a way to
>   inform the users that something went wrong with the process? A
>   rollback changes feature (either via program, or SQL), so that any
>   incomplete data in the database will be undone?

As we discussed in the comments, **transactions** will address many of your concerns.

> A transaction comprises a unit of work performed within a database
>   management system (or similar system) against a database, and treated
>   in a coherent and reliable way independent of other transactions.
>   Transactions in a database environment have two main purposes:
>
> 1. To provide reliable units of work that allow correct recovery from failures and keep a database consistent even in cases of system
>      failure, when execution stops (completely or partially) and many
>      operations upon a database remain uncompleted, with unclear status.
> 2. To provide isolation between programs accessing a database concurrently. If this isolation is not provided, the program's outcome
>      are possibly erroneous.

<sub>[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction)</sub>

### Transactions in .Net

As you might expect, the database is integral to providing transaction support for database-related operations. However, creating transactions from your business tier is quite easy and allows you to use a single transaction across multiple database calls.

*Quoting from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469959/transactions-should-be-handled-in-net-or-sql-server/12470061#12470061):*

I see several reasons to control transactions from the business tier:

- Communication across data store boundaries. Transactions don't have to be against a RDBMS; they can be against a variety of entities.
- The ability to rollback/commit transactions based on business logic that may not be available to the particular stored procedure you are calling.
- The ability to invoke an arbitrary set of queries within a single transaction. This also eliminates the need to worry about transaction count.
- Personal preference: c# has a more elegant structure for declaring transactions: a `using` block. By comparison, I've always found transactions inside stored procedures to be cumbersome when jumping to rollback/commit.

Transactions are most easily declared using the `TransactionScope` ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)) abstraction which does the hard work for you.

```
using( var ts = new TransactionScope() )
{
    // do some work here that may or may not succeed

    // if this line is reached, the transaction will commit. If an exception is
    // thrown before this line is reached, the transaction will be rolled back.
    ts.Complete();
}
```

Since you are just starting out with transactions, I'd suggest testing out a transaction from your .Net code.

1. Call a stored procedure that performs an INSERT.
2. After the INSERT, purposely have the procedure generate an error of any kind.
3. You can validate your implementation by seeing that the INSERT was rolled back automatically.

### Transactions in the Database

Of course, you can also declare transactions inside a stored procedure (or any sort of TSQL statement). [See here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174377.aspx) for more information.

Comment: TransactionScopes are pretty nasty if the DB and web app are on different machines, especially if the web app is externalized.  With many security teams you'd be lucky if it is even an option.  Internalized apps may fare better.

Comment: How so? (curious about your experience) I regularly use them across machines without issue (also had a few of those setups audited). The DTC is required in certain scenarios, but that can be setup fairly easily (and securely). The transaction scope isn't doing that much other than providing a tracking/synchronization mechanism that the database (or other transaction-aware entity) can use.

Comment: Yes, it was an issue with the DTC.  I think our issue was trust delegation.  In one case (company A), we were hosting on other people's servers-- everything worked well locally, but production didn't support this and the security team had no plans to implement it.  Company B just said it was so much of a headache (maybe due to the sensitive nature of the data and their size) that it wasn't even an option.  I don't know the details.  I did like the idea it because it can handle multiple sql transactions, but in the end they deemed it either unsafe or too costly in terms of headache.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. If you have control over the environment (and people familiar with Windows admin), the DTC isn't that big of a deal. I don't think there is really a security risk because no data is passed around the network, only transaction metadata. Also, escalation to the DTC only occurs under specific circumstances (usually in larger, distributed applications). Still, I can see how it can be a stumbling block.

Comment: @ps2goat, how so? Are there performance / security issues? The web app and database server are on different machines, but in the same location, and the same network / domain.

A lot of other sub-companies access it the web app, though, and often they are not in the same location.

Comment: @zack_falcon there are security implications to everything, but you should be fine if 1) you require DTC and 2) the IT department knows how to set this up.  I think the reason we tried to use the DTC was because of the way the database layer was working.  We didn't use a single sql transaction per unit of work, but per database call.  The DTC allows your TransactionScope to rollback several otherwise committed SQL transactions as well as changes to .NET-side stuff, I believe.  See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/197528/Configure-Distributed-Transaction-In-a-System

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same SQLConnection, or other connection types that implement `IDbConnection`, you can do something similar to transactionscopes but without the need to create the security risk that is a transactionscope.

In VB:

```
Using scope as IDbTransaction = mySqlCommand.Connection.BeginTransaction()

   If blnEverythingGoesWell Then
      scope.Commit()
   Else
      scope.Rollback()
   End If

End Using
```

If you don't specify commit, the default is to rollback the transaction.